# IllegalArgumentException: Cannot draw recycled bitmaps

Tags: android, listview, bitmap

So I have a `ExpandableListView` and inside the child views I have a `ListView`. When I click on one of the items it opens another activity. The problem occurs when I press back and click on another list item. When I do that I get the mentioned exception. I never use a bitmap, so I really don't know what is causing the problem, is the redrawing of the items the problem or?

I read (ref. [Caching Bitmaps](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/cache-bitmap.html) ) that I should implement a caching mechanism, but I don't know how to start and what should I cache if I don't use any bitmaps? What am I missing here?

The Logcat:

```
09-10 05:48:03.345: E/AndroidRuntime(21011): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-10 05:48:03.345: E/AndroidRuntime(21011): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot    draw recycled bitmaps
09-10 05:48:03.345: E/AndroidRuntime(21011):    at android.view.GLES20Canvas.drawBitmap(GLES20Canvas.java:789)
09-10 05:48:03.345: E/AndroidRuntime(21011):    at android.view.GLES20RecordingCanvas.drawBitmap(GLES20RecordingCanvas.java:118)
09-10 05:48:03.345: E/AndroidRuntime(21011):    at android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable.draw(BitmapDrawable.java:393)
09-10 05:48:03.345: E/AndroidRuntime(21011):    at android.widget.ImageView.onDraw(ImageView.java:967)
09-10 05:48:03.345: E/AndroidRuntime(21011):    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:13707)
09-10 05:48:03.345: E/AndroidRuntime(21011):    at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12645)
09-10 05:48:03.345: E/AndroidRuntime(21011):    at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12689)
09-10 05:48:03.345: E/AndroidRuntime(21011):    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:13423)
09-10 05:48:03.345: E/AndroidRuntime(21011):    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2928)
09-10 05:48:03.345: E/AndroidRuntime(21011):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2797)
09-10 05:48:03.345: E/AndroidRuntime(21011):    at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12643)
09-10 05:48:03.345: E/AndroidRuntime(21011):    at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12689)
09-10 05:48:03.345: E/AndroidRuntime(21011):    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:13423)
09-10 05:48:03.345: E/AndroidRuntime(21011):    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2928)
09-10 05:48:03.345: E/AndroidRuntime(21011):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2797)
09-10 05:48:03.345: E/AndroidRuntime(21011):    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:13710)
09-10 05:48:03.345: E/AndroidRuntime(21011):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:467)
09-10 05:48:03.345: E/AndroidRuntime(21011):    at android.widget.ScrollView.draw(ScrollView.java:1576)
09-10 05:48:03.345: E/AndroidRuntime(21011):    at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12645)
09-10 05:48:03.345: E/AndroidRuntime(21011):    at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12689)
09-10 05:48:03.345: E/AndroidRuntime(21011):    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:13423)
09-10 05:48:03.345: E/AndroidRuntime(21011):    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2928)
09-10 05:48:03.345: E/AndroidRuntime(21011):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2797)
09-10 05:48:03.345: E/AndroidRuntime(21011):    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:13710)
09-10 05:48:03.345: E/AndroidRuntime(21011):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:467)
09-10 05:48:03.345: E/AndroidRuntime(21011):    at android.widget.HorizontalScrollView.draw(HorizontalScrollView.java:1562)
09-10 05:48:03.345: E/AndroidRuntime(21011):    at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12645)
09-10 05:48:03.345: E/AndroidRuntime(21011):    at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12689)
09-10 05:48:03.345: E/AndroidRuntime(21011):    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:13423)
09-10 05:48:03.345: E/AndroidRuntime(21011):    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2928)
09-10 05:48:03.345: E/AndroidRuntime(21011):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2797)
09-10 05:48:03.345: E/AndroidRuntime(21011):    at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12643)
09-10 05:48:03.345: E/AndroidRuntime(21011):    at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12689)
09-10 05:48:03.345: E/AndroidRuntime(21011):    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:13423)
09-10 05:48:03.345: E/AndroidRuntime(21011):    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2928)
09-10 05:48:03.345: E/AndroidRuntime(21011):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2797)
09-10 05:48:03.345: E/AndroidRuntime(21011):    at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12643)
09-10 05:48:03.345: E/AndroidRuntime(21011):    at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12689)
09-10 05:48:03.345: E/AndroidRuntime(21011):    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:13423)
09-10 05:48:03.345: E/AndroidRuntime(21011):    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2928)
09-10 05:48:03.345: E/AndroidRuntime(21011):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2797)
09-10 05:48:03.345: E/AndroidRuntime(21011):    at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12643)
09-10 05:48:03.345: E/AndroidRuntime(21011):    at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12689)
09-10 05:48:03.345: E/AndroidRuntime(21011):    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:13423)
09-10 05:48:03.345: E/AndroidRuntime(21011):    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2928)
09-10 05:48:03.345: E/AndroidRuntime(21011):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2797)
09-10 05:48:03.345: E/AndroidRuntime(21011):    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:13710)
09-10 05:48:03.345: E/AndroidRuntime(21011):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:467)
09-10 05:48:03.345: E/AndroidRuntime(21011):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.draw(PhoneWindow.java:2211)
09-10 05:48:03.345: E/AndroidRuntime(21011):    at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12645)
09-10 05:48:03.345: E/AndroidRuntime(21011):    at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12689)
09-10 05:48:03.345: E/AndroidRuntime(21011):    at android.view.HardwareRenderer$GlRenderer.draw(HardwareRenderer.java:1198)
09-10 05:48:03.345: E/AndroidRuntime(21011):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.draw(ViewRootImpl.java:2173)
09-10 05:48:03.345: E/AndroidRuntime(21011):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performDraw(ViewRootImpl.java:2045)
09-10 05:48:03.345: E/AndroidRuntime(21011):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1854)
09-10 05:48:03.345: E/AndroidRuntime(21011):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:989)
09-10 05:48:03.345: E/AndroidRuntime(21011):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:4351)
09-10 05:48:03.345: E/AndroidRuntime(21011):    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:749)
09-10 05:48:03.345: E/AndroidRuntime(21011):    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:562)
09-10 05:48:03.345: E/AndroidRuntime(21011):    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:532)
09-10 05:48:03.345: E/AndroidRuntime(21011):    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:735)
09-10 05:48:03.345: E/AndroidRuntime(21011):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
09-10 05:48:03.345: E/AndroidRuntime(21011):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
09-10 05:48:03.345: E/AndroidRuntime(21011):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
09-10 05:48:03.345: E/AndroidRuntime(21011):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5191)
09-10 05:48:03.345: E/AndroidRuntime(21011):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-10 05:48:03.345: E/AndroidRuntime(21011):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
09-10 05:48:03.345: E/AndroidRuntime(21011):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:795)
09-10 05:48:03.345: E/AndroidRuntime(21011):    a
```

The code:

My expandable list adapter:

```
public class StaffExpandableListAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {

private ArrayList<StaffGroup> staffGroups;
private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
private Resources resource;
private RoomAdapter ra;

private Context context;

public StaffExpandableListAdapter(Context context,
        ArrayList<StaffGroup> staffGroups) {
    this.staffGroups = staffGroups;
    this.layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    this.resource = context.getResources();
    this.ra = new RoomAdapter(context);

    this.context = context;
}

@Override
public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    StaffChild staffChild = staffGroups.get(groupPosition)
            .getStaffDetails();
    return staffChild;
}

@Override
public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    return childPosition;
}

@Override
public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition,
        boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    final StaffChild staffChildInfo = (StaffChild) getChild(groupPosition,
            childPosition);
    ViewHolderChild holder;
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = layoutInflater
                .inflate(R.layout.child_row_staff, null);
        holder = new ViewHolderChild();
        holder.contact = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.tv_staff_contact);
        holder.consultation = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.tv_staff_consultation);
        holder.locations = (ListView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.lv_staff_locations);

        holder.noRoomLocation = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.no_room_location);
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolderChild) convertView.getTag();

    }

    holder.contact.setText(staffChildInfo.getContact().trim());

    holder.consultation.setText(staffChildInfo.getConsultation().trim());
    String roomId = staffChildInfo.getRoomId();

    final ArrayList<RoomLocation> roomLocationInfos = new ArrayList<RoomLocation>();
    String[] roomIdForSearch = roomId.split(":");
    if (roomIdForSearch.length <= 1) {
        holder.noRoomLocation.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        holder.locations.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }else{
        holder.noRoomLocation.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        holder.locations.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        for (int i = 1; i < roomIdForSearch.length; i++) {
            ra.openToRead();
            roomLocationInfos.add(ra.getRoomLocation(Integer
                    .valueOf(roomIdForSearch[i].trim())));
            ra.close();
        }

        String[] items = new String[roomLocationInfos.size()];
        int i = 0;
        for (RoomLocation rl : roomLocationInfos) {
            items[i++] = formatLocationName(rl.getName());

        }

        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(context,
                R.layout.item_location, R.id.tv_item_location, items);
        holder.locations.setAdapter(adapter);
        adapter.notifyDataSetInvalidated();
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        Utility.setListViewHeightBasedOnChildren(holder.locations);

        holder.locations.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {
                startBuildnigPlanActivityInSearchMod(
                        roomLocationInfos.get(position).getX(),
                        roomLocationInfos.get(position).getY(),
                        roomLocationInfos.get(position).getBuildingId(),
                        roomLocationInfos.get(position).getFloorId());

            }

        });
        holder.locations.setFocusable(false);

    }

    return convertView;
}

@SuppressLint("DefaultLocale")
private String formatLocationName(String locationNumber) {
    String location1Format[] = locationNumber.split(":");
    String buildingName = location1Format[0].trim();
    String roomName = location1Format[1].trim();
    return roomName + " (" + buildingName.toUpperCase(Locale.getDefault())
            + ")";
}

@Override
public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
    return 1;
}

@Override
public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
    return staffGroups.get(groupPosition);
}

@Override
public int getGroupCount() {
    return staffGroups.size();
}

@Override
public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
    return groupPosition;
}

@Override
public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded,
        View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    StaffGroup staffGroupInfo = (StaffGroup) getGroup(groupPosition);

    ViewHolderGroup holder;
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = layoutInflater
                .inflate(R.layout.group_row_staff, null);
        holder = new ViewHolderGroup();
        holder.staffId = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.tv_staff_id);
        holder.staffName = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.tv_staff_name);
        holder.groupIndicator = (ImageView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.iv_group_indicator);
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolderGroup) convertView.getTag();
    }

    if (isExpanded) {
        holder.groupIndicator.setImageDrawable(resource
                .getDrawable(R.drawable.iv_expanded));
    } else {
        holder.groupIndicator.setImageDrawable(resource
                .getDrawable(R.drawable.iv_not_expanded));
    }

    holder.staffId.setText(staffGroupInfo.getId().trim());
    if (staffGroupInfo.getTitle().trim().equals("No data")) {
        holder.staffName.setText(staffGroupInfo.getStaffName().trim());
    } else {
        holder.staffName.setText(staffGroupInfo.getStaffName().trim()
                + ", " + staffGroupInfo.getTitle().trim());
    }

    return convertView;

}

@Override
public boolean hasStableIds() {
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    return true;
}

public void startBuildnigPlanActivityInSearchMod(){
    ...
}

/**
 * ViewHolderGroup class for group view
 * 
 * 
 * 
 */
static class ViewHolderGroup {
    TextView staffId;
    TextView staffName;
    ImageView groupIndicator;

}

/**
 * ViewHolderChild class for child view
 * 
 * 
 * 
 */
static class ViewHolderChild {
    ListView locations;
    TextView contact;
    TextView consultation;
    TextView noRoomLocation;
}
```

}

The `ListView` is created inside the `getChildView` and so is the `setOnItemClickListener`. In my Activity I call normally the `ExpandableListView`. Hope this helps?!

Comment: can you post your code here?

Comment: It's a pretty huge code snippet, I can try to post only the important parts. Are you interested in a specific part of the code or?

Comment: I think there is a lot of space to paste your code

Comment: Looking at Logcat, can you identify where the error occurred? Post that part of code only. Otherwise post the Logcat first.

Comment: I want to to see your list adapter only and activity from where you are using it

Comment: Your logcat showing that you are trying to draw something in your ImageView which is not in your code. Are you using `ImageView` ?

Comment: I use an ImageView groupIndicator for the GroupView. But I have that in my other ExpandableListViews, there it was never a problem. I used ImageView in my ListView layout, but I deleted it and I get the same exception?

Comment: @GrIsHu I added now the entire Adapter. You can see that I have only the one ImageView in the GroupView. But as I mentioned I use it everywhere in my ExpandableListViews it was never the problem.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you need answer anymore, but I had the same problem, and I found this solution : 
I was using this function :

```
Bitmap thumbnail = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bmp, w, h, true)
if (!bmp.isRecycled()) {
    bmp.recycle();
}
bmp = null;
```

By reading the description of this method, I have found :

> "Creates a new bitmap, scaled from an existing bitmap, when possible.
>   **If the specified width and height are the same as the current width and height of the source bitmap, the source bitmap is returned and no
>   new bitmap is created**."

So basically, in this case, w and h are matching my "bmp" width and height, so the createScaledBitmap() function WILL NOT create a new object, but use the source one (bmp) and the "bmp" address will be used on my "thumbnail" variable. And if I try to recycle bmp (thinking that it will not be used anymore), I am wrong, because this same address is still used by the variable "thumbnail", and the rest of my code won't work.

So here is my simple solution :

```
Bitmap thumbnail = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bmp, w, h, true);
if (!thumbnail.equals(bmp)) {
    if (!bmp.isRecycled()) {
        bmp.recycle();
    }
    bmp = null;
}
```

Hope this will help someone !

Answer (score 1):

Try using this:

```
if (!bitmap.isRecycled())
           {
             bitmap.recycle;
           }
```

and then create your bitmap.

Comment: But I don't use a bitmap :/ Am I missing something?

Comment: @Aksiom Do you have an imageview in R.layout.child_row? Or imagebutton?

Comment: @user2045570 No I don't. I have 6 TextViews and 1 ListView thats all i use in that layout.